Issue with reload anime.js code after swup transition
I created the project online:
two html pages where before the closing body tag I added the swup library (version 3) and anime (contained in the "vendors.min.js" file), the anime code is inserted into the html code, inside the tag element.
Page transition with swup works, fine but it doesn't reload the animations from the "anime.js" library.
How do I write a function where the "anime.js" animations are executed immediately after the "swup.js" library transaction?
I tried with the documentation on the site "https://swup.js.org/" but they are incomplete and don't work... it's starting to get frustrating, can someone with experience help me? Thank you
Here the replit URL:
https://replit.com/@gbisb75/Swupjs-and-animejs?v=1

Please include the minimal necessary code inside your question (not in a zip), you can even use the [<>] button to create a runnable Stack Snippet. Take a look at How to Ask and its linked resources for more info.

After a few weeks and after repeated attempts I was unable to resolve. Is there someone who can help me? Thank you

Please, could someone help me?
Here the URL with all the files:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/swup-js-and-anime-js-conflict-3m5y34
Thanks for attention
